# How to use the 'reset picture & size' button in a Macro in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm dealing with many documents created by formal Word.

There are many equations converted into inline shapes with a fixed size.

I've found that using the 'reset picture & size' button can recover them to normal.

[the 'reset picture & size' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNIsF.png)

But because of the inline shapes property, I can't select all of them at the same time and use the button. So I want to use a Macro to do it.

I've known there is a reset method defined -- InlineShape.Reset method (Word).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshape.reset

But it only presents the 'reset picture' button, so how can I achieve the latter 'reset size'?

I've found the property scale for InlineShape Objects too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshape.scaleheight

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshape.scalewidth

But changing them to 100 is useless.

the following is my Macro Code.

```
Sub reset_all_picture_size()
Dim n
    For n = 1 To ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(n).reset
        With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(n)
             .ScaleHeight = 100
             .ScaleWidth = 100
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
```

I'm a student from China so may cause some Chinese English, plz excuse me.

Comment: Surprisingly, when I run twice the code that I have written, it works correctly.